# PL/SQL Dynamic Where Clause - Single Quote Around Dynamic String?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Simple question - If I'm trying to build a dynamic query and run it in a PL/SQL Stored Procedure, how do I enclose the variable in single quotes so that it is called correctly?

For example:

I first declare a variable to hold a cursor's column value.  I also declare a variable to hold the dynamic query:

```
vTest VARCHAR(200);
l_cur_string VARCHAR2(128);
```

After defining my cursor, I loop through it like so:

```
For entry in c1
LOOP
vTest:= entry.variable;

 l_cur_string := 'SELECT ex1, ex2FROM exTable WHERE col1= || vTest;
END LOOP;
```

Of course, when I print out the dynamic query, it doesn't have the single quotes around `vTest`.  I've tried adding them, but nothing I do compiles correctly.

Any help for a simple question?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with these queries? It should be rare to use dynamic SQL, most often static SQL is sufficient. Even if you really *need* to use dynamic SQL, you can still use [bind variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#BHCGEFCA). Don't leave yourself open to [SQL injection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#CHDFCHHJ). Describe your process so that we can help you.

Comment: Thank you.  Essentially, I've composed a stored procedure that returns a list of batch jobstreams in the order that they run.  Now, what I'm trying to do is loop through those jobstreams and cross-reference them with the jobs that they contain.  There is no user interaction with this stored procedure.  However, I still think I will look into bind variables and modifying this code to use static SQL.  Thank you for that reference!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Double the single quotes that you want to appear within the string:

```
l_cur_string := 'SELECT ex1, ex2FROM exTable WHERE col1= '''|| vTest || '''';
```

Remember, though, that embedding a string directly within an SQL expression is a quick route to an exploit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the word of warning.  Although there is no user action with this stored procedure, I think I should still use best practices to avoid developing a bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

Try these 2 snippets

```
    DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
    DECLARE @columnList varchar(75)
    DECLARE @city varchar(75)
    SET @columnList = 'CustomerID, ContactName, City'
    SET @city = '''London'''
    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM customers WHERE City = ' + @city
    print @sqlCommand
    --EXEC (@sqlCommand)


    DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
    DECLARE @columnList varchar(75)
    DECLARE @city varchar(75)
    SET @columnList = 'CustomerID, ContactName, City'
    SET @city = 'London'
    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM customers WHERE City = @city'
    print @sqlCommand
    --EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@city nvarchar(75)', @city = @city
```

Comment: That's not valid Oracle PL/SQL syntax